# Is it true for convex optimization problems?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose we have a convex optimization problem. Hence the objective function and all the constraint functions are convex. Suppose that one of the constraint is such that $f_i(x)\leq m$. We know that the optimal value of the problem will be a non-increasing function of $m$. But is it also true that if we draw the optimal value as a function of $m$ then the upper level set (epigraph) will be a convex set? That is if the optimal value has stopped decreasing after a certain value of $m$ then it will not further decrease no matter how much we increase the value of $m$.

If it is not generally true, then is there some category of convex optimization problems when it is true? Thank you.